# Run a ejb outside it's container in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ejb, ejb-3.0, netbeans-6.9

I am using netbeans to run my web application. Now, in my web application project, I have a jsp code which call a servlet and that servlet call's a EJB and shows the output of EJB in a jsp page. Now, to run my application I am right clicking on application and then pressing run button. However, I want to run my ejb outside of the ejb container. Can anybody help me how to do that ? Means how to run a ejb outside it's ejb container in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Concept of EJB without container is bit problematic. EJB container and EJB are fundamentally connected. Container for example creates instances of EJB, offers many kind of services (transactions for example) to EJB, and controls it during lifecycle.

If for example options for testing EJB, then [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-junit.html) page provides instructions about how to use embedded GlassFish with NetBeans.

Comment: Thanks Mikko. My ejb application provides transactions. Another point is that it is not posible to run ejb application outside it's container ? Actually I don't want to test it, I want it for actual run.